# Trying to multiply a certain data cell by another certain data cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Due to misunderstanding using my real scenario I am going to create one.

Here is the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
num1df = pd.DataFrame({'Number 1': [1, 4, 3, 2, 100]})
num2df = pd.DataFrame({'Number 2': [1, 2, 'NaN', 4, 5]})
num3df = pd.DataFrame({'Number 3': [1, 2, 3, 1000, 0]})
numsdf = pd.concat([num1df, num2df, num3df], axis=1, join="inner")
print(numsdf)
```

```
   Number 1 Number 2  Number 3
0         1        1         1
1         4        2         2
2         3      NaN         3
3         2        4      1000
4       100        5         0
```

I want to be able to do the follow addition. Column Number 1 row 4 plus column Number 3 row 3 = Column Number 2 row 2. 100 + 1000 = 1100 (the answer should be in place of the NaN)

This should be the expected outcome:

```
   Number 1 Number 2  Number 3
0         1        1         1
1         4        2         2
2         3     1100         3
3         2        4      1000
4       100        5         0
```

How would I do that? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: It is 3 different DataFrames? Why? It is not 3 columns in same DataFrame?

Comment: I actually had that before the current post but still couldn't figure out how to do it. This is merely the latest iteration of my long line of attempts trying to get it working. Do you have a solution for that one? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Notice: Solution working only if sme indices in all 3 DataFrames.

If possible replace non numeric values by missing values and then forward filling last non missng values in same column use:

```
marketcapdf['Market Cap'] = stockpricedf['Stock Price'] * 
                            pd.to_numeric(outstandingdf['Outstanding'],
                                          errors='coerce').ffill()
```

If working in one DataFrame:

```
df['Market Cap'] = df['Stock Price'] * 
                   pd.to_numeric(df['Outstanding'],
                                 errors='coerce').ffill()
```

EDIT: If need multiple by shifted second column with no change first value use:

```
numsdf['new'] = numsdf['Number 1'] * numsdf['Number 2'].shift(fill_value=1)
print(numsdf)
   Number 1  Number 2  new
0         5         1    5
1         4         2    4
2         3         3    6
3         2         4    6
4         1         5    4
```

EDIT1: I create new columns for better understanding:

```
num1df = pd.DataFrame({'Number 1': [1, 4, 3, 2, 100]})
num2df = pd.DataFrame({'Number 2': [1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5]})
num3df = pd.DataFrame({'Number 3': [1, 2, 3, 1000, 0]})
numsdf = pd.concat([num1df, num2df, num3df], axis=1, join="inner")

#add by shifted values
numsdf['new'] = numsdf['Number 1'].shift(-1, fill_value=0) + numsdf['Number 3']
#shift again
numsdf['new1'] = numsdf['new'].shift(-1, fill_value=0)
#replace NaN by another column
numsdf['new2'] = numsdf['Number 2'].fillna(numsdf['new1'])
print(numsdf)
   Number 1  Number 2  Number 3   new  new1    new2
0         1       1.0         1     5     5     1.0
1         4       2.0         2     5     5     2.0
2         3       NaN         3     5  1100  1100.0
3         2       4.0      1000  1100     0     4.0
4       100       5.0         0     0     0     5.0
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question. Thanks, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @lotsofliquidity - Can you add how looks expected ouput not like text, by like dataframe?

Comment: I changed the scenario a little but I have added the output. Thanks, so sorry for all the confusion! Last change.

Comment: The numbers in new1 column are not the same as in Number 2 column. They are required to all stay the same with the exception of NaN being turned into 1100 by multiplying Number 1 column element 4 by Number 3 column element 3. Thanks

Comment: @lotsofliquidity - is possible add more data and explain? Not understand this replacement

Comment: I am unsure how to break it down anymore.
The columns should all remain the same with the exception of NaN which should be the result of two other cells being added together.

Comment: if check `new2` column it is expected output?

Comment: Yes, the new2 column is correct but the other columns have not remained the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = numsdf.iloc[4, 0]
bar = numsdf.iloc[3, 2]
numsdf.at[2, 'Number 2'] = foo + bar
```

Output:

```
   Number 1 Number 2  Number 3
0         1        1         1
1         4        2         2
2         3     1100         3
3         2        4      1000
4       100        5         0
```